# The induced map in K-theory, degree property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $f:S^{2} \rightarrow S^{2}$ such that $f(z)=z^{n}$.
How can we show that the induced map (in K-theory):
$f^{*}:\tilde{K}(S^{2}) \rightarrow \tilde{K}(S^{2})$ must have the following form: $f^{*}(\alpha)=deg(f) \cdot \alpha?$

Comment: Viewing $S^2$ as $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ is a generator of $\tilde{K}(S^2) $.

Answer (score 5):

As [abx indicates](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303606/the-induced-map-in-k-theory-degree-property#comment756739_303606) in a comment, it suffices to show this for the tautological bundle $\mathcal O(1)\to S^2$, since it generates $\tilde K(S^2)$.

By the Whitney sum formula, the first Chern class defines a group homomorphism $\tilde K(S^2)\to H^1(S^2)$; this sends $\mathcal O(1)$ to a generator. The pullback map $f^*\colon H^1(S^2)\to H^1(S^2)$ is multiplication by $\mathrm{deg}(f)$ (this is in Hatcher), so

$$c_1(f^*\mathcal O(1)) = \mathrm{deg}(f) c_1(\mathcal O(1)).$$

Since line bundles are classified by their Chern classes, $f^*\mathcal O(1) \cong (\mathcal O(1))^{\otimes(\mathrm{deg}(f))}$, which suffices. (If $d :=\mathrm{deg}(f)$ is negative, $L^{\otimes d}$ means $(L^*)^{\otimes(-d)}$.)